# GLSL shapes signed distance field implementation explanation?

Tags: glsl, mathematics, signed-distance-field

I'm trying to understand all primitives In [this article](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm).After hard work I just learn Sphere and Cube , I wrote description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326366/glsl-cube-signed-distance-field-implementation-explanation/49726668#49726668).

I could draw 2D shapes but I have trouble understanding 3D below codes:

[image: Tours 2D]

Torus - signed - exact

[image: Tour 3D]

```
float sdTorus( vec3 p, vec2 t )
{
  vec2 q = vec2(length(p.xz)-t.x,p.y);
  return length(q)-t.y;
}
```

[image: Length]

I can't imagine how this shape drew and I don't know why two length used here.

---

[image: Cone 2D]

Cone - signed - exact

[image: Cone 3D]

```
float sdCone( vec3 p, vec2 c )
{
    // c must be normalized
    float q = length(p.xy);
    return dot(c,vec2(q,p.z));
}
```

I don't know why dot product used here?

I'm confused please help me to understand this shapes.I hope someone explain each shape.

Comment: What about them do you have trouble understanding? It's hard to explain without knowing what the specific problem is.

Comment: @DanHulme my specific problem Is that I don't know how functions used to draw 3d shapes like dot product in cone shape and like using two length in tours shape

Comment: @DanHulme I edit my question and add some detail that what is my problem I hope you help me to understanding this shapes.

Comment: Please do not edit your question after an answer has been posted. If you have follow up questions, post them separately.

Comment: @Federico I'm sorry I removed new part , I wanted ask as a new question but I thought Instead of asking several questions It's better to ask one question.

Comment: No, the opposite is quite true instead, SE sites prefer several well defined questions to one overly broad question

Comment: I think your edit made it clear that you have a wider problem understanding linear algebra or signed distance fields, that explaining a bunch of shapes to you one at a time won't fix. Perhaps if you could isolate the common factor that's hard to understand about all the shapes, that would make a better question.

Comment: @DanHulme that's right I should learn more algebra and ask my specific problems thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit late tot he game but I had a similar issue, I have no idea how to simplify the Cone but I rewrote the Torus function in a way that seemed more natural to me below.

float SdTorus(float3 position, float innerRadius, float outerRadius)
{
    float thickness = .5 * (outerRadius - innerRadius);
    float2 q = float2(length(position.xz) - outerRadius + thickness, position.y);
    return length(q) - thickness;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Torus

A torus is defined by two parameters: the major radius, and the minor radius. The major radius (`t.x`) is the radius of the big ring (in red in the diagram), and the minor radius (`t.y`) is the radius of the circular cross-section. The `x` and `y` here are just indices into the vector: they're unrelated to the x and y axes.

The left side of the diagram shows the xz plane, and the right side shows a cross-section with y going horizontally.

[image]

`p.xz` is the projection of the point onto the plane of the torus, so `length(p.xz)-t.x` gives the distance from that projected point to the inside of the torus. (I've labelled it $r$ on the diagram.) `p.y` is the distance from the point to the plane of the torus, so the length of the vector ($r$, `p.y`) is the distance from the point to the inside of the torus. (Computing the length of a two-element vector is a handy way to use Pythagoras' theorem to find the hypotenuse of the triangle.)

## Cone

Like the torus, the cone code uses the fact that the shape is symmetric about an axis: the z axis in this case. The cone is defined by a unit vector `c` that's normal to the surface of the cone, and the apex of the cone is at the origin. Similar to the above, `length(p.xy)` gets the distance from the point to the z axis, so that we can work in the plane where the cone is a triangle. `vec2(q,p.z)` is the projection of `p` into this plane. The dot product projects this vector onto the direction `c`: how far the point is along this direction tells us how far it is from the surface of the triangle.

[image]